# Adding score + name in each cell in excel file

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm trying to get this problem fixed. I'm creating a program which stores the score in a spreadsheet but when it does, it does not write the score and name in different cell. I have tried adding the column string/row string but always getting error, some guide and help will be appreciated.

So far this is what I have done:

!(http://postimg.org/image/6zn9l43bj/)!

I tried to get a heading saying name and the users name below in each cell and same with score and need some starting point/help

```
ClassA = open('classa.csv', 'w')
ClassB = open('classb.csv', 'w')
ClassC = open('classc.csv', 'w')
start = True
while start:
user =(input("What is your name?"))
form =(input("Which Group are you in A/B or C ")).lower()
import re
import random
from random import randint
score = 0
for i in range(3):
    first_num = random.randint(1,10)
    second_num = random.randint(1,10)
    choice = (first_num+second_num) 


    if choice == first_num+second_num:
        print ("Question (%d)" % (i+1))
        print (first_num)
        print("Add (+)")
        print(second_num)

    check = True
    while check:
        answer = (input('enter the answer: '))
        if not (re.match('-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$', answer)):
            print("Only input numbers")
        else:
            check = False
            answer = int(answer)




    if answer == (choice):
        print("It's correct!")
        score +=1

    else:
        print("It's wrong!")
        print ("The correct answer is: ", choice)
        print('')


print(user)



if form == 'a':
    ClassA.write("Name: "+str(user) + ' ' + "Score: "+str(score)+"/10" + '\n')
elif form == 'b':
    ClassB.write("Name: "+str(user) + ' ' + "Score: "+str(score)+"/10" + '\n')
elif form == 'c':
    ClassC.write("Name: "+str(user) + ' ' + "Score: "+str(score)+"/10" + '\n')

yesorno = input("Restart?, Y or N ").lower()
if yesorno == 'y':
    start = True
elif yesorno == 'n':
    start = False

ClassA.close()
ClassB.close()
ClassC.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: I cannot see where any part of this question is related to Excel. You seem to be trying to create CSV files from some app that definitely isn't Excel VBA. I suggest that you remove the Excel tag and replace with CSV

Answer (score 0):

A bit of background: CSV stands for [Comma Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), oddly enough Values are quite often separated by semicolons in CSV files and, in fact, (I think) <strike>Excel won't recognise columns if you use commas, but it will if you use semicolons</strike>. **Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, this probably depends on regional settings, if in your country the decimal point is usually a comma (e.g. most of Europe) use `;`, if it's usually a point use `,` as separator.

So, back to your question: you are not separating your values, use this instead (notice the semicolon):

`ClassA.write("Name: "+str(user) + '; ' + "Score: "+str(score)+"/10" + '\n')`

I wouldn't recommend writing the `Name:` and `Score:` prefixes either, I would go with a header row (`Name; Score; Max Score`) and something like this:

`ClassA.write("{0}; {1}; {2}\n".format(user, score, max_score))`

See also: [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: umm , i tried what you suggested a while ago but it didnt work , i tried again but it wont print it on each cell for example the name on A1 and the score on B2 separate , tbh i dont know if this is possible :( .

Comment: @ImYu: Have you tried opening your resulting CSV files with notepad? That should give you an idea of what's going wrong: each line is a row, each "value" separated by a semicolon is a cell. Also try cleaning up your code.

Comment: This is incorrect. While the separator doesn't have to be a comma, it often is, and Excel recognizes it. It depends on your regional settings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: @DougGlancy You're most likely right, since with the default settings of where I live it never works, I guess I grew the habit of using semicolons instead. My answer does answer OPs question though, in that int he posted code he/she was not separating the values ;). He/she is probably experiencing other problems now.